# Angular nav-link stops working after routerLinkActive activates

Tags: html, angular

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column nav-justified">
  <div id="sidebar-item" *ngFor="let item of sidebarItems">
    <li class="nav-item" routerLink="{{item.url}}">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="{{item.url}}" [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><fa-icon [icon]="item.icon" class="fa_icon ml-n3 m-2"></fa-icon>
        <span class="item_title">{{ item.title | uppercase }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <hr>
  </div>
</ul>
```

I have 4 items in sidebarItems list and it generates 4 nav-links. When the first one is active the other three don't work and when one of the other three is active the first one doesn't work.

[First active, second doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3pdx.png)

[Third active, second works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMQxR.png)

[Third active, first doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEhxy.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: you have a routerLink="{{item.url}}" on the <li>, try removing it

Comment: @Maryannah https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dkw93y

Comment: @JensAlenius i've had problem before that, tried if adding it there would fix something (it didn't)

Comment: Ok but it should not be there. Then try change to [routerLink]="item.url"

Comment: And change [routerLinkActive] to: routerLinkActive="active" it will add a class 'active' on the link that corresponds to the route. No need for brackets when its not set to a component property

Comment: Can you check my update?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `div` inside the `ul` tag and move you `*ngForm` on the `li`

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column nav-justified">
    <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="let item of sidebarItems">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="{{item.url}}" routerLinkActive="active">
        <span class="item_title">{{ item.title | uppercase }}</span>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Forked and working stackblitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9oexwb

**Edit:** Your solution works on a wide enough monitor because your styles are wrt the window width. You need to work a lot on your styles but a quick fix would be to change the `padding` to `margin` for `#dashboard[_ngcontent-xsb-c0]` as 200px. Stackblitz updated.

Comment: Still the same issue on my side. Click on configuration then try to click on cycle...

Comment: The stackblitz is working [](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9oexwb)
Click on Open in new window at the top right corner on stackblitz 
Good Work @Saksham